# can i use radio button list as Submit button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, submit, radiobuttonlist

i have:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="selectedYesNoQuestionBlock7" runat="server" 
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Question7GotAnswered">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

....

<div id="btCreate" style="margin-left: 254px; margin-top: 10px;">
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Categorize" ID="btCategorize" />
</div>
```

i want to submit wothout button, just after selecting list item. is it possible and how??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `AutoPostBack="true"` for your `RadioButtonList`

```
<asp:RadioButtonList AutoPostBack="True" ID="selectedYesNoQuestionBlock7" 
      runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="Question7GotAnswered">
 ...
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the event exposed by the `RadioButtonList` control and put your code in the proper event handler. I guess you should set to *True* `AutoPostBack` of the control as well.